# Django Pagination with multiple models (tables)

Tags: python, django, django-models, pagination

We have multiple models (tables) for storing orders category wise of a customer .

```
class BookOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    order_details = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class ShoeOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    order_details = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class MobileOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    order_details = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now we need to show list of orders based on created_at to our customers. But it should be paginated.
Can anybody suggest me how to use Django pagination with multiple models ?

Comment: did my answer help you? Please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this to `chain` your querysets:

```
from itertools import chain

book_orders = BookOrder.objects.all()
shoe_orders = ShoeOrder.objects.all()    
mobile_orders = MobileOrder.objects.all()
orders = list(
            sorted(
                chain(book_orders, shoe_orders, mobile_orders),
                key=lambda objects: objects.created_at
            ))
paginator = Paginator(orders, 5)
```

But I think the better way is to refactor your models and use [Multi-Table-Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Then you have a base class `Order` and you can do the pagination on this class:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    order_details = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class BookOrder(Orders):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

Comment: What will happen if created_at field is different name like (created, created_at, created_on) ?